# How can I add custom meta fields in categories?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, categories, meta-boxes

Does anyone have any idea how to add custom meta fields while making categories and fetch them in the loop in WordPress? I was wondering how to do that without hacking the WordPress core, but if I do – it won't become a hindrance to update WordPress in the future.

A plugin I have found that comes close is [Wp-Category-Meta](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-meta/), but it doesn't have the ability to add checkboxes as fields in Edit Categories.

[image: screenshot]

This will be very useful as users can make certain categories "featured", and then the code can use that meta value in the loop to style "featured" categories differently.

Answer (score 3):

<del>**The problem:**
Wordpress does not have a structure nor method to store "meta" values for taxonomies.</del>

## UPDATE 2017: WP 4.4+ has "term meta"!

For working with term metas use these:

[`update_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/)

[`get_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)

[`delete_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_term_meta/)

[`add_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/)

**The *Actions* below are still valid though! :)**

Additional reading: [4.4 Taxonomy Roundup](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/23/4-4-taxonomy-roundup/)

## Solution for WP version <= 4.3.x and COMMON actions

#### [Actions:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions_.28Admin.29)

1. `create_category` and `edit_category` for category **edit**
2. `category_add_form_fields` and `category_edit_form` for category **form fields**

There are more actions than I've presented, but they seem to be **deprecated** (according to developer.wordpress.org).

**The reason I chose the actions that I chose:**

 - They work on WordPress 4.4.2

 - Due to lack of documentation I assumed these are the new ones replacing the deprecated ones...

#### Functions:

1. [`get_option( $option, $default );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)
2. [`update_option( $option, $new_value, $autoload );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)

`update_option` has two great abilities:

a) It craetes the option when such option does not exist yet

> Unless you need to specify the optional arguments of add_option(),
>   update_option() is a useful catch-all for both adding and updating
>   options.

b) `$new_value` **can be an integer, string, array, or object.**

You may ask, **why to use array/object?** ...well, because each option = 1 database row => you probably want to store your category options in *one* row :)

## The CODE

```
  function my_category_form_fields($tag_object){
    //output/display extra form fields, e.g. by echo ...
    //ADD EXTRA SPECIFIC FIELD TO LATER CHECK IF IT'S CATEGORY SAVE/EDIT!
    //(see note at 'edit_category' action...)

    if( !empty($tag_object['term_id']) ){
      //edit category form specific
      //...load existing options with get_option( $option, $default );
    } else {
      //create category form specific
    }
  }

  function my_category_save(){
    //CHECK FOR YOUR EXTRA SPECIFIC FIELD TO CHECK IF IT'S CATEGORY SAVE/EDIT
    //(see note at 'edit_category' action...)

    //SECURITY CHECK
    if( empty($_POST['EXTRA_SPECIFIC_FIELD']) || ! current_user_can('manage_categories') )
       return null;

    //save your form values using update_option()
    //Recommendation:
    //Add "category_" prefix and $category_id to your option name!
  }

  add_action( 'create_category', 'my_category_save', 10, 1 ); 

  //Runs when a category is updated/edited,
  //INCLUDING when a post or blogroll link is added/deleted or its categories are updated
  //(which causes the count for the category to update)
  add_action( 'edit_category',   'my_category_save', 10, 1 ); 

  add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'my_category_form_fields', 10, 1 ); 
  add_action( 'category_edit_form',       'my_category_form_fields', 10, 1 );
```

#### Create or Edit?

You might wonder whether you are creating or saving a category - this not documented yet (as far as I know), but from **testing:**

1. Edit save => `$tag_object` is `object` and contains some properties, most notably:

   - `term_id`
   - `taxonomy`
   - `filter`
2. Create save => `$tag_object` is just a regular `string` "category" - I guess this might change in the future...

## General taxonomy

There are also actions like these for taxonomies in general - check [these actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Taxonomy_and_Terms).

Comment: Of course there are also plugins that can do all this for you :) Important is to look whether they can use the WordPress' own *_termmeta table in 4.4+ , it is then reusable and does not create unnecessary tables :)

Comment: I stumbled across your post in an attempt to unravel why my code isn't working as intended - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/417562/term-meta-not-saved-when-adding-the-first-category. I'm using the majority of what you have listed but for some odd reason, the term meta doesn't save the first time around but does for every other submission thereafter.

Comment: @Motivated it seems that you used different hooks - the proper hooks are `create_category` (not creat**ed**_category) as well as `create_category`, (not edit**ed**_category) - did that resolve your issue? The ones with "...ed" fire ***after*** the term cache has been cleaned. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Jaz, 
It looks like the plugin you mention in your original question has been updated to include a checkbox field ([included in v1.2.3](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-meta/other_notes/))

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Category SEO Meta Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-seo-meta-tags/) plugin will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an updated and refactured version of this plugin to be found here:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-taxonomy-category-and-term-fields/

Also added a WYSIWYG editor fieldtype.